# Changing the output DTO (return value) of the GetAll method in an AsyncCrudAppService

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, dto, aspnetboilerplate, application-layer

I'm using ABP's `AsyncCrudAppService` in my AppServices. Here's my interface:

```
public interface IAssetRequisitionAppService : IAsyncCrudAppService
    <AssetRequisitionDto, Guid, GetAllInput, AssetRequisitionDto, AssetRequisitionDto, AssetRequisitionDetailsDto>
{ }
```

And the service:

```
public class AssetRequisitionAppService : AsyncCrudAppService
    <AssetRequisition, AssetRequisitionDto, Guid, GetAllInput, AssetRequisitionDto, AssetRequisitionDto, AssetRequisitionDetailsDto>, 
    IAssetRequisitionAppService
{
    public AssetRequisitionAppService(IRepository<AssetRequisition, Guid> repository) : base(repository)
    { }
}
```

Now, I believe all these standard CRUD methods will return the default type (which is `AssetRequisitionDto` in my case). But, what I want to do is to return a different type for `Get()` and `GetAll()` methods.

`Get()` should have a much more detailed DTO with subproperties of the Navigation props. But `GetAll()` should have a much less detailed one just to populate a table.

Is there a way to override the return types in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I noticed I'll eventually need more complex filtering methods anyway. So, I created my custom types and methods.

First, I created my own `GetAllInput` derived from `PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto`. It's suited for most of my services, as I usually need to query the data related to employees and locations:

```
public class GetAllInput : PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto
{
    public long? PersonId { get; set; }
    public long? LocationId { get; set; }
    public EEmployeeType? EmployeeType { get; set; }
}
```

After that I wrote a `GetAll` method for each of my services. They all return a `PagedResultDto<>` so I can use it's functionalities in presentation layer. Here's one example below:

```
//MovableAppService

    public PagedResultDto<MovableLineDto> GetAllLinesRelatedToUser(GetAllInput input)
    {
        Logger.Info("Loading all movables related to current user");

        IQueryable<Movable> queryable = null;
        if (input.PersonId.HasValue)
        {
            if (input.EmployeeType == EEmployeeType.Recorder)
            {
                var recorder = _personRepository.GetAll()
                .OfType<Employee>()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == input.PersonId);
                var authorizedStorageIds = recorder.StoragesAuthorized.Select(y => y.Id);

                queryable = _repository.GetAll()
                    .Where(x => authorizedStorageIds.Contains(x.StorageOfOriginId));
            }
            else if (input.EmployeeType == EEmployeeType.UnitManager)
            {
                var locationCodes = _locationRepository.GetAll()
                    .Where(x => x.ManagerInChargeId == input.PersonId)
                    .Select(x => x.Code);

                foreach (var code in locationCodes)
                {
                    queryable = _locationRepository.GetAll()
                        .Where(x => x.Code.StartsWith(code))
                        .SelectMany(x => x.AssignmentDocs)
                        .SelectMany(x => x.Movements)
                        .OfType<Assignment>()
                        .Where(x => x.TimeOfReturn == null)
                        .Select(x => x.Asset)
                        .OfType<Movable>();
                    queryable = queryable.Concat(queryable);
                }
            }
            else if (input.TenantIdsOversee.Count() > 0)
            {
                var overseer = _personRepository.GetAll()
                    .OfType<Overseer>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == input.PersonId);
                var overseeingTenantIds = overseer.TenantsOversee.Select(y => y.Id);

                queryable = _repository.GetAll()
                   .Where(x => overseeingTenantIds.Contains((int)x.TenantId));
            }
            else if (input.EmployeeType == EEmployeeType.Employee)
            {
                queryable = _personRepository.GetAll()
                    .OfType<Employee>()
                    .Where(x => x.Id == input.PersonId)
                    .SelectMany(x => x.AssignmentDocs)
                    .SelectMany(x => x.Movements)
                    .OfType<Assignment>()
                    .Where(x => x.TimeOfReturn == null)
                    .Select(x => x.Asset)
                    .OfType<Movable>();
            }
        }
        var list = queryable.ToList()
                .OrderBy(x => x.Category.Definition);
        var items = _objectMapper.Map<IReadOnlyList<MovableLineDto>>(list);

        return new PagedResultDto<MovableLineDto>(items.Count, items);
    }
```

Btw, aaron's answer is probably valid for **ASP.NET Core** projects. But my project is in **MVC EF6**, so those annotations are not available for me.

Now I'm marking this as the answer but if there's a more elegant way, I'm happy to see and I'll change my mark then.

Comment: You asked to override the return type of `GetAll` and your answer is to create an unrelated method?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is *some way*.

```
// using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

[ActionName(nameof(GetAll))]
public PagedResultRequestDto MyGetAll(PagedResultRequestDto input)
{
    return input;
}

[NonAction]
public override Task<PagedResultDto<UserDto>> GetAll(PagedResultRequestDto input)
{
    return base.GetAll(input);
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2859

Comment: Umm, I tried but those annotations (`ActionName` and `NonAction`) are used in the controller code I believe. I need something for the Application layer. Though I also see you mentioned AspNetCore library here. I should emphasize my project uses the MVC template. Not Core.

Comment: `NonActionAttribute` is in `System.Web.Mvc` for MVC5.